# ActionMailer doesn't send any email, but gaves no error - in AWS EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, devise, amazon-web-services, actionmailer

Im trying to use ActionMailer in a Rails2 app in a AWS EC2; I have configured it, I created the model, the views and everything, and when I try to send an email, it gaves me no error, but the email never reached the final user.

This is my configuration in environment.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

And everything is like in the books. I don't know what to do, I have installed Devise and when I try to send emails (for user confirmations or things like that) it works. I put the configuration of action_mailer to work with SMTP of GMail, and it works for me but Devise throw me errors...

What should I do? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to use the external SMTP server because there are strict [limitations sending emails from AWS EC2 machines](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances).

We have successfully used Devise and SMTP together in some of projects at [BitNami](http://bitnami.org). What errors are you getting?

You may also consider using [Amazon email service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).
There are some gems out there to add support for it like [amazon-ses-mailer](http://rubygems.org/gems/amazon-ses-mailer).

Comment: Hi, sorry I just see your message, well if I use the SMTP of GMail it sends the emails with my gmail account and not with the website email that I put in the configuration. Also, it gaves me some errors with Devise.. I have to check those logs. What steps did you follow to configure an external SMTP service?